# Cannot resolve symbol 'GoogleCloudMessaging' GCM

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-studio

I am trying to get `GCM` working in my app (to notify users when our hours change, or when we have any promos going on), but I keep getting the error `Cannot resolve symbol 'GoogleCloudMessaging'` when trying to use the Google Cloud Messaging API.

I am using the newly released Android studio IDE to code this.

Here is my GcmBroadcastReciever.java code :

```
import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    Context ctx;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm; // I get the error here

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context); //error
        ctx = context;
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent); //cannot resolve method here
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) { //error
            sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) { //error
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else {
            sendNotification("Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        }
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

    // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                new Intent(ctx, Activity.class), 0);

        Toast.makeText(ctx, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> The sections below guide you through the process of setting up a GCM
>   implementation. Before you start, make sure to set up the Google Play
>   Services SDK. **You need this SDK to use the GoogleCloudMessaging methods**. Strictly speaking, the only thing you absolutely need this
>   API for is upstream (device-to-cloud) messaging, but it also offers a
>   streamlined registration API that is recommended.

Did you [set up the Google Play Services SDK](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)?

You have to :

1. Install the Google Play services SDK
2. Reference the `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/` library project in your Android project.

> To install the Google Play services SDK for development:
>
> ```
>  1. Launch the SDK Manager.
>      - From Eclipse (with ADT), select Window > Android SDK Manager.
>      - On Windows, double-click the SDK Manager.exe file at the root of the Android
>        SDK directory.
>      - On Mac or Linux, open a terminal and navigate to the tools/ directory in 
>        the Android SDK, then execute android sdk.
>  2. Install the Google Play services SDK.
>     Scroll to the bottom of the package list, expand Extras, select Google Play 
>     services, and install it. 
>     The Google Play services SDK is saved in your Android SDK environment at
>     <android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/.
>  3. Install a compatible version of the Google APIs platform. 
>     If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for
>     Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and
>     install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target. 
>     Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform
>     include Google Play services.
> ```

Comment: i had it installed, but not imported into my project as a dependency.
importing it fixed my problems, cheers

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do #2, but then I read unify's answer and tried the "sync gradle" after doing step #1 here.  That combo worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Android Studio:

1) Downloaded the Google Play SDK (using the SDK Manager):

[image: SDK Manager]

2) Don't forget to click on the "Synch Project with Gradle Files" button

[image: Synch Project with Gradle Files]

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you are in Android Studio, make sure that in your `build.gradle` you have:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

and then run `build`.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have add dependencies on build.gradle > Sync > Build - Clean Project.

Worked for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning your project. Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using an old tutorial but GCMRegistrar is a deprecated API class.

Please use the [GoogleCloudMessaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) API instead.

Check this for complete tutorial [push notification using gcm](http://www.androidwarriors.com/2015/10/push-notification-using-gcm-in-android.html)