# Dependencies for GCM Push Notification

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-cloud-messaging

I have been working on GCM Push Notification for my upcoming project and I have been facing several confusion regarding its implementations. I have followed the following links:

1. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/
2. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

The implementation that I ended up with works quite fine with the emulator(not on all of them). Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/x5RNwRQ6) to my registration implementation.

1. It works fine with an emulator running on platform 4.2.2
2. It isn't working with an emulator running on platform 2.3.3

My experiences so far tells me that, on the client side, the following things must be ensured to enable GCM properly:

1. Google Play Services installed
2. The device synced with a Google account.

**Am I right?**

So I have the following questions to ask:

1. What are the client side dependencies that I should be worried about while implementing GCM? What should I check in my code?
2. When I uncomment the lines from 110 to 114 in the above code to check play services, I receive the following error log http://pastebin.com/C2BJkiyt . But it still allows me to register. What's wrong?
3. When I run the working code(working on emulator) on a real device having Android 2.3.6, it doesn't work. It also doesn't work on a device having ICS.

Thanks for the time.

Comment: for your error, you are attempting to start activity without closing alert dialog. This is the error of memory window leak.

Comment: Emulator running on platform 2.3.3 is synced with google account.

Comment: you need to check whether client is registered with Google play account? and does the mobile installed Google play service?

Comment: @AnAndroid well I edited my question and I am not sure if the client needs to have play account and service installed. About your earlier comment, how do I prevent from starting activity?

Comment: @URAndroid sorry I didn't get what you said. The emulator isn't synced with google account. Even if I sync with a google account, it still doesn't work, when I click on register button, it navigates me to the account settings option inside settings->account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering to GCM with the deprecated library method `GCMRegistrar.register`. This can still work, but it requires on pre-4.0.4 Android devices with a logged-in Google account.

Google encourage you to stop using the deprecated library, and instead use the register method of GoogleCloudMessaging class, which doesn't require a Google account even in older Android versions. See [their GCM Demo](http://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/app/DemoActivity.java?r=44e0469692d7d10a104cd689d3045a56971f90ce) for an example.

The code that checks for play services is only relevant if you switch to the new registration method.

As for why the deprecated registration method doesn't work for you on some devices, you'll have to include the logcat to get help with that.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am trying the demo that you have given. So in this new method, the client device does not have to sync a Google account, right? Any other issues/dependencies that I should look into?

Comment: @Pro.metal Well, if you haven't done so yet, you have to setup the Google Play Services SDK. You can read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619450/cannot-resolve-symbol-googlecloudmessaging-gcm/). And you are correct about not having to sync a Google account.

Comment: I have implemented and had some trouble with google play services library issues. I think I have solved that, still I am getting errors. This is my [log report](http://pastebin.com/Fgkv2mSj). And this is my [code](http://pastebin.com/RzBsEhKP).

Comment: apparently I am having trouble with the new implementations. So I stay with the old implementations. So if syncing google account is mandatory for this implementation, when should I check this? How should I check this issue when user wants to register in my GCM?