# The Google Play services resources were not found - Push Notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm following the Google Tutorial to install **Push Notification** on Android.
I'm using **Google Play Services Module** because the Google Cloud Messaging was recently *deprecated*.

Tutorial : [Google Cloud Messaging - Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html)

But when I launch the app I have this errors :

```
11-06 13:37:30.119  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1821 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.119  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1821 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.119  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1816 (common_google_play_services_install_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.119  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1812 (common_google_play_services_enable_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.119  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1826 (common_google_play_services_update_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.119  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1823 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1820 (common_google_play_services_network_error_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1821 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1821 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1818 (common_google_play_services_invalid_account_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1821 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1813 (common_google_play_services_install_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1810 (common_google_play_services_enable_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1824 (common_google_play_services_update_button) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1821 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1815 (common_google_play_services_install_text_tablet) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1814 (common_google_play_services_install_text_phone) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1811 (common_google_play_services_enable_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1825 (common_google_play_services_update_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1822 (common_google_play_services_unsupported_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1819 (common_google_play_services_network_error_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1817 (common_google_play_services_invalid_account_text) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.129  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 1821 (common_google_play_services_unknown_issue) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
11-06 13:37:30.139  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
11-06 13:37:30.220  20097-20097/com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
```

You can see here my **source code**

```
//basic import ...

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class AppMainTabActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    /**
     * Substitute you own sender ID here. This is the project number you got
     * from the API Console, as described in "Getting Started."
     */
    String SENDER_ID = "7984****78";

    /**
     * Tag used on log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";

    TextView mDisplay;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    Context context;

    String regid;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = getApplicationContext();

        // Check device for Play Services APK. If check succeeds, proceed with
        //  GCM registration.
        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);

            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }

    // You need to do the Play Services APK check here too.
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    /**
     * Check the device to make sure it has the Google Play Services APK. If
     * it doesn't, display a dialog that allows users to download the APK from
     * the Google Play Store or enable it in the device's system settings.
     */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current registration ID for application on GCM service.
     * <p>
     * If result is empty, the app needs to register.
     *
     * @return registration ID, or empty string if there is no existing
     *         registration ID.
     */
    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's {@code SharedPreferences}.
     */
    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
        // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences, but
        // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
        return getSharedPreferences(AppMainTabActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * @return Application's version code from the {@code PackageManager}.
     */
    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                    .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
     * <p>
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * shared preferences.
     */
    private void registerInBackground() {
        new AsyncTask() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
                    // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                    // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
                    // is using accounts.
                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the device
                    // will send upstream messages to a server that echo back the
                    // message using the 'from' address in the message.

                    // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                    // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                    // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                    // exponential back-off.
                }
                return msg;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                mDisplay.append(o + "\n");
                Logger.logit("onPostExecute","o");
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Sends the registration ID to your server over HTTP, so it can use GCM/HTTP
     * or CCS to send messages to your app. Not needed for this demo since the
     * device sends upstream messages to a server that echoes back the message
     * using the 'from' address in the message.
     */
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {
        // Your implementation here.
        PushNotification.register(OpenUDID.value(this), regid, new AsyncHRHandler(this, true) {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String s) {
                super.onSuccess(s);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Stores the registration ID and app versionCode in the application's
     * {@code SharedPreferences}.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param regId registration ID
     */
    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

However **Google Play Service** has been *added*.

[image: Project Tree thedjnivek]

On my **module settings**

[image: Module settings thedjnivek]

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<!-- For notification push -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<permission android:name="com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.thedjnivek.android.emarchespublics" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".fragmentmodule.AppMainTabActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".activity.PDFActivity"
        android:label="activity_pdf"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIza**************mGE4Mq88"/>

</application>
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile: "com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.+"
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

I don't know where the problem is. Someone can't help me ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve symbol 'GoogleCloudMessaging' GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619450/cannot-resolve-symbol-googlecloudmessaging-gcm)

Comment: Everyday Google is making changing and breaking old versions that sometimes makes developers full with tear. May God be with you my dear brother :-)

Answer (score 3):

I never played with the push notifications but I'm working with the google play services. You should add the google-play-services_lib folder as a separate project and add it as a library into your Android project.

1. Import the google-play-services_lib (also tick the copy to workspace).
   You can find the google-play-services_lib in the 
   sdk floder -> extra > google -> google_play_services -> libproject -> google-play-services_lib
2. Set the newly created project as a library (in eclipse -> build path -> android -> tick the "is Library" and ok.
3. Go to the build path of your android project -> android -> add -> add the google-play-services_lib library you just created.

I hope it helps (-:

Answer (score 2):

You should not copy google-play-services.jar directly into your project. Instead you need add reference to

> [android-sdk]\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

library t your project. To do this please follow item 4 of [these](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#step_1_download_the_sample_app) instructions. In Android Studio there should be similar procedure.

The reason is GPS library refers to it's own (com.google.android.gms.R) resources from precompiled JAR.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the `google-play-services_lib` as an module in my project and I removed the jar but know I can't compile : `com.google.android.gms.* not found.` :s

Comment: I added again the .jar and now I can compile. The `google-play-services_lib module` is still in my project but the same error occurred.

Comment: Looks like you missed something. You definitly should not copy jar file manually. Try to follow [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16639227/1992063) steps to integrate library to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I was just working on this same issue the last couple days. My issues were related to the Drive API, but the solution would potentially help regardless of which part of the Google API you're using.

I use IntelliJ IDEA for my development as well. What I had to do was call up the Project settings and add some additional dependencies to my app. Referencing the Google Play Services JAR file is one part of this. To get the resources, you need to reference the project itself so it compiles the R class for Play Services. Here's what I did:

1. Imported a module that referenced the google-play-services_lib for the source
2. Opened Module Settings for my app module
3. Clicked the Dependencies tab
4. Added a new "Jars or Directories" dependency
5. Browsed to the SDK location for google-play-services.jar and referenced it
6. Added a new Module dependency that referenced the project for google-play-services_lib

FYI, I have the google-play-services.jar reference as a global library, so I can actually include it easily in any project, but that's not necessary for this to work. You just need to have references to both the JAR and the module to get it to compile the Play Services resources object.

In my proguard.cfg file for my app project, I added this:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.**
```

The Proguard configuration modification may not be necessary.

After I made these changes, it came together pretty quickly. I will say that Google's API documentation for implementing calls to their API is VERY out of date and incorrect. They mention referencing the JAR, but don't say anything about referencing the project. I vaguely remember them glossing over the fact that you need to actually compile a jar manually yourself, but it's not clear exactly what you need to reference in their documentation.

Hope this helps!