# NoClassDefFoundError for GooglePlayServicesUtil on android

Tags: android, eclipse, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use google cloud messeging in my android app. It worked for me however after organizing my classes in packages and cleaning my project it stopped working, I get following error : http://pastebin.com/uWgYW9fn

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-18 20:57:44.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15967):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil 11-18
>   20:57:44.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15967):
>   activity.MainActivity.checkPlayServices(MainActivity.java:491) 11-18
>   20:57:44.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15967):
>   activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:72) 11-18
>   20:57:44.649: E/AndroidRuntime(15967):    at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)

Basically I moved my activity from

```
myproject.android
```

to

```
myproject.android.activity
```

and it stopped working with the above error. For gcm setup I did the following:

```
1. Install Google Play services with SDK manager.
2. Import relevant classes into my activity
3. Added the google-play-services_lib.jar to build path
4. added it as library project
```

[image]

My project is a maven project, however there is no maven repo for the cloud messaging service. Any ideas whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GooglePlayServices should be added as a library project (see Android menu), not as a JAR in the build path.

See more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619450/cannot-resolve-symbol-googlecloudmessaging-gcm/16620087#16620087).