# Google Play Services library loaded, referenced but still won't work, not even in sample projects?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use the Google Play Services library for the Cloud Messaging functionality, but without any luck.

1. I have updated Eclipse to the latest version, and downloaded the Google Play Services lib via SDK Manager.
2. Imported the library into the Eclipse workspace
3. Referenced the library in the sample App's proprietaries

But as u can see in the images, "The import com.google.android.gms.common cannot be resolved" message appears, and none of the library commands works.

What could be wrong?
Thanks

Hi-Rez screenshot:
http://edmondvarga.com/demo/screenshot.jpg

[image: Sample 1]

[image: sample 1]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve symbol 'GoogleCloudMessaging' GCM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619450/cannot-resolve-symbol-googlecloudmessaging-gcm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your lib project look like this:

[image]

Comment: Not quite @Kai, added a picture:[Picture](http://edmondvarga.com/demo/lib.jpg) - Why is different?

Comment: @EdmondTamas Try following Google guide again (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html), that's how I got mine working. When you "Copy the library project at <android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ to the location where you maintain your Android app projects" make sure it indeed contains google-play-services.jar in \libs

Answer (score 0):

Add the Google Play services version to your app's manifest

```
 <meta-data
 android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
 android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Saj at Applexus Technologies. I have added as a child in the app manifest.