# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging using java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

This is really annoying. I've wasted a whole day but haven't received any proper result. I'm trying to add Google Cloud Messages into my app. I'm using Eclipse last version. ADT last version. I've added google-play-services_lib as Library, added the jar file in Build path but my app drops at the code line below:

```
GoogleCloudMessaging regId = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(_.appContext);

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError!
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like a proguard obfuscation issue.

Comment: no proguard I've used. It seems the app do not see google-play-services_lib classes. I do not understand why.

Comment: Try to clean/rebuild the project in Eclipse.

Comment: It is runtime error, adding jar to classpath solves compile time errors, you need to make sure jar is getting packaged to make it available during run time. Assuming this jar is supported in run time, -->Go to Eclipse right click on project --> Go to "Java Build Path" --> Go to tab "Order...." and select the jar.

Comment: Already did all those obvious solutions

Comment: Have you selected the "Google APIs" of your selected API version as Project Build target of your project? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619450/cannot-resolve-symbol-googlecloudmessaging-gcm

Comment: Of course. It doesnt work on both machines with eclipse I have.

Comment: Downvoted? really funny. I've just unswered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the bug of SDK and Eclipse. The library google-play-service.jar didn't attached in a proper way. Just full reinstalling Eclipse (with ADT) and SDK helped to me. The connected question about all classes (not only Cloud Messages) is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903978/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-for-any-google-play-services-feature).
Do not forget about [memory increasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916324/android-complation-freezes-if-google-play-services-jar-lib-is-added-into-my-hell) in eclipse.ini file.