# Android compilation freezes if google-play-services.jar lib is added into my helloworld android project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-play-services

I'm trying to find out the core of the google-play-services.jar bug for my android app.
The previous links are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29903978/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-for-any-google-play-services-feature) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898396/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-android-gms-gcm-googlecloudmessaging). I've wasted 2 whole days to fix the problem but no result. Even I've tried to reinstall Eclipse, Android SDK in 2 different machines and tested on two different devices. But no result. The last experiment gave me incredible error: Eclipse doesn't build (doesn't create apk-file) for default hello-world project if I just add google-play-lib.jar into my project. No more code. Google API's are enabled. I'm using the last eclipse version, SDK - the lates updates (24.1.2, 22.0.1, etc.) more on screenshot.
[image]

The screenshot explains the problem. I'm few minutes later eclipse crashes! WHY??? Imazing! Beautifull!
[image]

The error text:

```
refreshing external folders blocked the user operation is waiting for background work to complete org.eclipse.jdt.croe.external.folders/.link0
```

Comment: Downvoted... hahaha funny:)

Comment: I don't see why you got downvote, but now that Android Studio is the official IDE and Gradle the official builder, maybe it would be the time to switch? Because this bug seems Eclipse-centric to me.

Comment: @shkschneider while I write this post I'm installing Android Studio:) I agree. Thank for the answer. This is the only solution I think.

Comment: It's not a solution per say, that's why I put it as a comment: it is just an Eclipse bug I guess. Try to report if Android Studio worked better and close you question if it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will freeze, so do this to ur eclipse config file. Increase the Xms and Xmx by doing it manually. U can find this file in Eclipse folder and file is named like this : eclipse.ini

So the Eclipse config should look like this.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```